# How to combinate runs of two different agents with multiple runs each one

Tags: simulation, agent, anylogic

I need to create a methode (or similar) which reads the runs of two agents and combinate them into one run.

Each agent has data base which contains multible parameters and each paramter has multible values, a value for each parameter for each run.

so how can I let the project run all these different alternatives and get me the different outputs for the combinations?

Answer (score 0):

Create a param-variation experiment and have 1 boolean parameter on Main "runFirstAgent". Setup your model to only load the first agent if `runFirstAgent== true`, otherwise let it run the second agent.

In the Param-variation experiment, setup the runs so it varies `runFirstAgent` accordingly.

Then, you can accumulate results from your runs in the experiment itself.

There are lots of example models that show you how to do it, check those out first ;-)